# Transactions without input addresses

Tags: wallet, transaction, address

I'm building a minting engine for a project and I found something strange today. One of the incoming transactions, which I pull from a Cardano Wallet (testnet) service has an input without an address. All the other transactions do have an input address. They're all transactions between two wallets I manage in ccVault, and always from wallet 1 to wallet 2.

So I'm wondering now, under which conditions does a transaction input not contain an address?

The transactions I'm talking about are the following.

#### Without input address (first try)

https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/transaction/44964910dee982af3f714a6e4f3e50670aa9f3ef90debced9b4785d6a28bc350

```
{
    ...
    "amount": {
        "quantity": 37023500,
        "unit": "lovelace"
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "id": "3c1c5b73ab66d18efa2540f59df345a702820833264519c69f9c79cbc07bce3c",
            "index": 1
        }
    ],
    ...
    "id": "44964910dee982af3f714a6e4f3e50670aa9f3ef90debced9b4785d6a28bc350",
    ...
}
```

#### With input address (second try)

https://testnet.cardanoscan.io/transaction/3f776bd594b43d6288bde265e5aa3aead414585ff664fef4736f0b42ce7db695

```
{
    ...
    "amount": {
        "quantity": 37023500,
        "unit": "lovelace"
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "quantity": 683493813,
                "unit": "lovelace"
            },
            "address": "addr_test1qp608umcxnpuj869hu2an658pegt8rsgtu9kh9tmfy3kqcktz647sk9ds3hkrg888edxrgc708mfw2cncldqzzq7em4qzrctsk",
            "id": "44964910dee982af3f714a6e4f3e50670aa9f3ef90debced9b4785d6a28bc350",
            "assets": [],
            "index": 1
        }
    ],
    ...
    "id": "3f776bd594b43d6288bde265e5aa3aead414585ff664fef4736f0b42ce7db695",
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Just to clarify, they are both outgoing transactions from Wallet 1 to Wallet 2. Only the first one doesn't arrive with an input address, while the second one does:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue boils down to the fact, that *"the wallet does not maintain a complete ledger but only a subset narrowed down to the assets belonging
to the wallet"* (see https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/2434#issuecomment-757169360)

It should show the addresses and assets only for outgoing transactions according to the docs here https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/api/edge/#operation/getTransaction

> assets and address are always present for outgoing transactions but
> generally absent for incoming transactions. This information is
> present on the Cardano explorer, but is not tracked by the wallet.

Not sure why it is actually showing for the other incoming transactions.

Anyhow that api is probably not the right tool for the job, but instead you need to use an explorer api like cardano-graphql or a service like Blockfrost, that will return the data through this endpoint: https://cardano-testnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/txs/44964910dee982af3f714a6e4f3e50670aa9f3ef90debced9b4785d6a28bc350/utxos *(see screenshot below)*

There is a feature request for this though in cardano-wallet here:

https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/2710

*(And another related issue here: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/2617)*

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. They are both transactions initiated from Wallet 1 to Wallet 2. I've done about 100 payments in the same direction, except for this one (with input address addr_test1qphxhe0l6v6...), they all arrived with an input address in Wallet 2.

Comment: Sorry you're absolutely right. Was just seeing that one address ("addr_test1qp608umcxnpuj869hu2an658pegt8rsgtu9kh9tmfy3kqcktz647sk9ds3hkrg888edxrgc708mfw2cncldqzzq7em4qzrctsk") in the outputs of the first and as the input for the second transaction. But its change only in the first tx. So my guess is it still might be related to the issue above, but I'll take another look at it

Comment: When pulling the json you posted above, are you using the same walletId parameter in both cases? For this endpoint: https://localhost:8090/v2/wallets/{walletId}/transactions/{transactionId}

Comment: In any case maybe you could look at the "direction" attribute also in the response, as for "incoming" transactions there are just few cases that the address field should be populated: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/2617#issuecomment-821864615 and here https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/issues/2434#issuecomment-757169360

Comment: Okay did some editing on this one, hope this answer works better. Although I can't exactly tell yet what is causing the info to be missing from the cardano wallet api in this specific case (there's a few options), the solution should stay the same :)

Comment: `When pulling the json you posted above, are you using the same walletId parameter in both cases? For this endpoint: localhost:8090/v2/wallets{walletId}/transactions/{transactionId}`

Yes, and in both cases the address is missing for those transactions. I could use the change address, which is the last one in the outputs. That one seems to be always present. So far I can see, it is.
 
But you're probably right about it not being the right tool for the job. I've got a cardano-db-sync server as well, so I'll try pulling the required information for there.
 
Thanks for your answers!>